# Mount directory as volume in Docker on Windows 10

Tags: image, docker, containers, volume, mount

I installed Docker on Windows 10 but I have an problem with mount directory (docker it is installed with virtualbox).

I want to mount this path -v /D/www/project_name:/usr/public/www . But I can not do that because I don't have permission.

If I try to mount -v /C/Users/Public/test:/usr/public/www, that works.

How can set permission on partition D? or on path D:www/project_name.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under windows 10 with the recent versions of docker (which relies on Hyper-V and not VirtualBox) you do not have this kind of issues anymore.

But if you do not have the choice, you should to mount shared directories into virtual box as shown there : http://developmentalmadness.com/2016/03/05/docker-permanently-mount-a-virtualbox-shared-folder/